# Android playlist query is inaccurate...?

Tags: java, android, playlist, mediastore

this seemingly simple issue is confusing me. I have the following code:

```
Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME},
            null,
            null,
            MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

    c.moveToFirst();
    Log.d("TestTest", String.format("Count is %d", c.getCount()));
    for (int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++) {
        c.moveToPosition(i);
        int id = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID));
        String s = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME));
        Log.d("TestTest", "HEY!  " + s + "  " + String.format("%d", id));
    }
```

The count is being reported as 1, and the apparently my only playlist is named 'm3u playlist'.

What's going on here? I have several playlists and just want to print a list of them.

Thanks for all answers!

Comment: Did you find where they are stored?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it took me this long to realize that Playlists created in the 'Music Player' app are not included in MediaStore.Audio.Playlists....

But I get it now.

Comment: Hi, Can you tell me how to create new playlist and add them to MediaStore.Audio.Playlists?